# Using Assetic's Css Rewriter outside of Symfony

Tags: assetic

Let me start by saying I have absolutely no idea what I *should* be doing because the documentation and available information on Assetic is either limited or Symfony oriented.

Here is my folder structure.

```
Assetic
   + assets
      + css
         + example.css
   + docs
   + src
   + tests
   + vendor
   + index.php
   + styles.php
```

Now, I have the following test code. Basically I cloned a clean copy of Assetic and ran `composer install`. Then I create an `index.php` file which simply links to my `styles.php` file with HTMLs `<link>` tag.

Here is my `styles.php`

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$assetPath = __DIR__.'/assets/css/example.css';
$assetBasePath = __DIR__.'/assets/css';

$asset = new Assetic\Asset\FileAsset($assetPath, array(), $assetBasePath, 'example.css');

header('Content-Type: text/css');

$asset->setTargetPath(__DIR__);

echo $asset->dump(new Assetic\Filter\CssRewriteFilter);
```

Here is my `example.css` stylesheet.

```
body {
    background-image: url('../img/background.png');
}
```

When I load up the `styles.php` in my browser I get the following output.

```
url('../img/background.png');
```

That's the same as the actual CSS. If I use the CSS URI Rewriter from Mr. Clay I get the expected output.

```
url('/Assetic/assets/img/background.png');
```

So what am I doing wrong with Assetic? I have no idea what paths I should be passing in and to where.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just a pretty hard time with it, but finally (after reading the doc. of webassets, python library on which assetic is based) I won over the lack of documentation.

Here you go

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$assetPath = __DIR__.'/assets/css/example.css';

$asset = new Assetic\Asset\FileAsset($assetPath, array(new Assetic\Filter\CssRewriteFilter), dirname($assetPath), '/assets/css');
// I assume the 'assets' directory is at the root of your website

header('Content-Type: text/css');

$asset->setTargetPath('/path/to/dumped/asset');
// As above, it's the path to the generated asset from your http root

echo $asset->dump();
```

I'm not sure to be very clear, so ask if you didn't understand something.

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to work. The target path, you mean an absolute path or a URL. From looking at the source of Assetic it seems to ask for a URL to the assets target.

Comment: Where I put dirname($assetPath), it's supposed to be the absolute path to the directory containing the css file.
'/assets/css' is the URL to the assets directory.
$asset->setTargetPath('/path/to/dumped/asset'); Here it's the absolute path to the directory containing the dumped assets.